# Using Google Markup for Gmail API: Json-ld or Microdata Not Working

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, json-ld, google-schemas

### Description of Problem

I am attempting to send an an email using gmail markup from my own computer using a client library (@googleapis)

I have not found a good reference for this and the documentation only includes examples for appscript [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action). However, I am doing most of my work in node JS.

My code takes in a multipart mime that is used inside `gmail.users.messages.send()` function, following that I would base64 encode my email and pass that into the raw property of the request body.

### What I tried

To get it working. I have tried multiple things:

1. Include JSON-LD and MICRODATA in a HTML script and loaded it as a `text/html`.
2. Included JSON-LD as a part in the multipart mime with content-type `application/ld+json`.
3. Another of my co-workers used gmail's api-explorer to try this. But it doesn't work too.

In this effort, when I inspect my email `Show Original` in gmail. I see the JSON-LD as part of the mime message in-tact, but I do not see any action or one-click buttons appearing, which is what I am aiming for.

I am dubious of this because I was searching the RFC5322 docs and I see nothing about JSON-LD or MICRODATA and I know gmail emails are meant to be compliant.

### Question

So, is there a way to get google markup to

Possible approaches may include that I run AppScript in node and send my mail from appscript, but, I would want to avoid this.

### Code

Here is the main body of my email before encoding:

```
var email = [
        'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"\r\n',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
        'From: Someones Name <*****@gmail.com>\r\n',
        'To: '+toPerson.name+' <'+toPerson.email+'>\r\n',
        'Subject: '+subject+'\r\n\r\n',

        '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
        'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n',

        message+'\n\n'+'Task: '+task+' assigned by '+taskAssigner+' to '+taskAssignee,
        '\r\n\r\n',


        '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n',

        htmlContent+'\r\n\r\n',

        //not working!
        '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
        'Content-Type: application/ld+json; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n',

        jsonld+'\r\n\r\n'

    ].join('')
```

```
  const emailEncoded = Base64.encodeURI(email);// do not need to add equals to end
    const messageEncoded = Base64.encodeURI(message);

    // setting up arguments to be sent
    const sendArgs = {
        auth,
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            raw: emailEncoded
        }

    };

    gmail.users.messages.send(sendArgs,
        // callback
        (err, res) => {
            if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
            // console.log(res)
            console.log('you just sent an email');
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
        });
```

The HTML part of my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Approve Expense",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://myexpenses.com/approve?expenseId=abc123"
    }
  },
  "description": "Approval request for John's $10.13 expense for office supplies"
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Testing JSON-LD here</h1>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Hi, what did your co-worker try with the API? What error did he get? Can you share what you have tried in Node-JS?

Comment: @Jescanellas He did not get an error but a succesful 200. He just used a simplified version of the mime above and 64 encode. I added some code to my question to give more context of what I did

Comment: @Jescanellas The main thing is that we do not get errors when sending the emails. But the expected markup, ie a button next to the subject of the email does not display succesfully

Comment: I have found that this issue has already been reported, so the markup function is not working at this moment.